# Caliburn Micro pass non generic parameter to new ViewModel

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, caliburn.micro

Caliburn Micro pass non generic parameter to new ViewModel in Windows Store App

I navigate from one Page to another and want to pass my own class instance like parameter to ViewModel.

I need something like this, only with replacing string to own class instance.

In FirstViewModel:

```
   NavigationService.NavigateToViewModel<SecondViewModel>("Hello");
```

In SecondViewModel:

```
    public string Parameter { get; set; }

    public ProjectPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
    {
        _navigationService = navigationService;
    }
```

With strings all works great. 
 It is possible to pass instance of own class?

Comment: Generally, passing complex object graphs is discouraged. You can [check out this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15251867/1180426), along with comments and workaround by Anders.

Comment: Yes, it's little trick helps me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Phone you can't pass complex object within navigation. You can treat it as a fundamenatal constraint nowadays.

Instead, if you want, you can use the EventAggregator with intention to pass a message. By the way, the EventAggregator pattern is commonly used for similar tasks in MVVM.