# Passing Objects using Caliburn Micro

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, winrt-xaml, caliburn.micro

i'm developing a small application for Windows 8.1.
It's just a simple CRUD app.

I'm using Caliburn.Micro (2.0.0-alpha2)

I have 2 UserControl and 2 Views (with relatives ModelViews)

Each view include one UserControl, but the idea was that a page can be composed using one or more userControl.

I got a listItem userControl, and a listItemPage
also a formItem UserContro and a CRUDItemPage

in my listItem UserControl i manage the list (taken from local db) and also the selection.

I want to select an item in my ListItemPage and initialize the value of the CrudItemPage.

But i want to know i can i pass the object selected from the list to the CrudItemPage...

I've used this in my listItemUserControViewModel

```
private Transporter _selectedItem;
    public Transporter SelectedItem
    {
        get 
        {

            return _selectedItem;
        }

        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.SelectedItem);
            //ShowMyMessage(_selectedItem);
            navigationService.NavigateToViewModel<TransporterCrudPageViewModel>(_selectedItem);
        }
    }
```

trying to pass the object to the CRUDPageViewModel and getting it using

```
public Transporter Parameter { get; set; }
```

but Parameter is always null.

My CrudView is a page that include my FormItem (userControl) and i want to initialize it with the values passed from CrudPageViewModel.

Is it possible?
I can do that without userControls...and i don't know why it doesn't work now

Comment: I think [this question and answers](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15251867/1180426) might be helpful.

Comment: thanks, but i can't understand why the value Parameter in my ViewModel is always null, and if i make something like that in my view it works `<StackPanel DataContext="{Binding Prameter}"  Margin="40" Orientation="Vertical">
            <TextBlock Text="Transporter Name" FontSize="35"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding trName}" FontSize="35"/>
        </StackPanel>`   Why i can't manage Parameter from viewmodel?

Comment: I tried but the solution proposed by Anders Gustafsson doesn't work for me

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek  According with the solution of Anders Gustaffson, i don't know where/how initialize the Parameter value in the CrudItemPage. The value of parameter is always null. take a look at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22659918/caliburn-micro-passing-object-between-viewmodel/22660638?noredirect=1#comment34521472_22660638)