# Caliburn Micro : passing Object between ViewModel

Tags: c#, mvvm, winrt-xaml, caliburn.micro

I'm developing a simple Crud Application (a windows 8.1 store application) using Caliburn Micro 2.0.0-alpha2

I'm in trouble with navigation between viewmodels, passing object.

I read many times the solution proposed by

> Anders Gustafsson ([How to pass parameter to navigated view model with WinRT Caliburn.Micro?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15251867/how-to-pass-parameter-to-navigated-view-model-with-winrt-caliburn-micro))

and i tried to adapt it to my scope. 
But the object is alwais null.

I need to pass a single object selected from a listView to my crudPage.
The crudPage is composed by an userControl that shown the FormView.
So i want to initialize this Form, with the values of the passed object. 
[image: solution proposed]

I think that the problem is that the "Parameter" is initialized only after the ViewModel is created, but i don't know how to fix that problem.

There is my  code, according with the idea of Anders Gustafsson

TransporterListViewModel (a list of Transporters from Database)

```
public class TransporterListViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public TransporterListViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
        : base(navigationService)
    {
        LoadData();
    }

    public async void LoadData() {

        _transporters = await TransporterService.GetAll();
    }

    private BindableCollection<Transporter> _transporters;

    public BindableCollection<Transporter> Transporters
    {
        get
        {
            return this._transporters;
        }
        set
        {
            this._transporters = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.Transporters);
        }
    }

    private Transporter _selectedItem;
    public Transporter SelectedItem
    {
        get 
        {

            return _selectedItem;
        }

        set
        {
            _selectedItem = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => this.SelectedItem);

            navigationService.Navigated += NavigationServiceOnNavigated;
            navigationService.NavigateToViewModel<TransporterCrudPageViewModel>(_selectedItem;);
            navigationService.Navigated -= NavigationServiceOnNavigated;
        }
    }

    private static void NavigationServiceOnNavigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs args)
    {
        FrameworkElement view;
        TransporterCrudPageViewModel transporterCrudPageViewModel;
        if ((view = args.Content as FrameworkElement) == null ||
            (transporterCrudPageViewModel = view.DataContext as TransporterCrudPageViewModel) == null) return;

        transporterCrudPageViewModel.InitializeTransporterForm(args.Parameter as Transporter);
    }
```

TransporterCrudViewModel (the page that cointains the UserControl to initialize)

```
public class TransporterCrudPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Transporter Parameter { get; set; }
    public TransporterFormViewModel TransporterFormVM { get; set; }

    public async void InitializeTransporterForm(Transporter enumerable)
    {
        TransporterFormVM = new TransporterFormViewModel(navigationService, enumerable);
        await SetUpForm(enumerable);
    }

    public async Task SetUpForm(Transporter t){
        TransporterFormVM.trName = t.trName;
        TransporterFormVM.trUrl = t.trUrl;

    }
    public TransporterCrudPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
        : base(navigationService)
    {
        Title = "TransporterCrud Page";
        //this.navigationService = navigationService;

        this.InitializeTransporterForm(Parameter);

    }
```

TransporterFormViewModel (the userContol to initialize)

```
    public class TransporterFormViewModel :ViewModelBase
{


    public string Title { get; set; }

    public Transporter Transporter { get; set; }

    public TransporterFormViewModel(INavigationService navigationService,Transporter trans)
        : base(navigationService)
    {
        Transporter = trans;
    }



    private string _trName;
    public string trName 
    {
        get
        {
            return _trName;
        }
        set
        {
            _trName = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => trName);
        }
    }


    public string trCode { get; set; }
    public string trUrl { get; set; }

    public int trId { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor `TransporterCrudViewModel` class you have:

```
this.InitializeTransporterForm(Parameter);
```

where `Parameter` is a property of type `Transporter` not initialized and you will call the method `InitializeTransporterForm` with a `null` parameter. Then you'll call `SetUpForm` method with a null value of the parameter `Transporter t`. I think you should initialize in some way this property.

Then, supposing you're continuing in your `TransporterListViewModel` class with this:

```
transporterCrudPageViewModel.InitializeTransporterForm(args.Parameter as Transporter);
```

in the method `InitializeTransporterForm`, you don't set the passed parameter as value of the property `Parameter` with something like this:

```
public async void InitializeTransporterForm(Transporter enumerable)
{
     TransporterFormVM = new TransporterFormViewModel(navigationService, enumerable);
     this.Parameter = enumerable; //setting the Parameter property..
     await SetUpForm(enumerable);
}
```

Beside these notes, you should put a breakpoint with your IDE in the line

```
transporterCrudPageViewModel.InitializeTransporterForm(args.Parameter as Transporter);
```

Make sure that the property `Parameter` of the `NavigationEventArgs` object is not null.

Comment: So, the problem is not the Parameter, Parameter is not null, but when the setup function is called `await SetUpForm(enumerable)`  i got this message exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
"

Comment: @ArghArgh There are some things about this implementation that I don't understand and that I think they're related to the `null` parameter, that's my point. Take a look at the value of `SelectedItem` property of `TransporterListViewModel` class. This value is passed as parameter of the `args` object of your event handler.

Comment: i've inserted frew lines of code, to show some properties of the object Transporter `Transporter tmp = new Transporter();
            tmp = args.Parameter as Transporter;
            if (tmp != null)
                Debug.WriteLine(tmp.trName);`  And the output show me the exception before the values (the value of the object is correct) Taht's the output "A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in CrudSampleMVVM.exe
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
marco"

Comment: the problem is that i try to get the value of Parameter before, that it's initialized. I don't know why Setup is called before..

Comment: Ok, i try to semplify my question. According with the solution of Anders Gustaffson, i don't know where/how initialize the Parameter value in the TrasporterCrudViewModel.

Comment: @ArghArgh This depends on what you're trying to achieve with your code and I cannot help you with that.

Comment: i'm just trying to pass an object from one viewModel to another. And use this object to initialize the View (associated to the second viewmodel) Thanks for your help. I hope that someone will help me to find a praticable solution.

Comment: there's the complete Project on github, if someone want to try to solve [GitHubLink](https://github.com/campioncino/CrudSampleMVVM/tree/master)

Comment: @ArghArgh Yes, I understood. With my answer, I suggested you to understand the reason why you pass first a null Parameter. I think you should remove the line `this.InitializeTransporterForm(Parameter);` in the constructor of `TransporterCrudPageViewModel`. Do you really need it? I'll have a look at your code on github later.